# Combine dataframes columns consisting of multiple values - Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two Spark dataframes that share the same ID column:

`df1`:

```
+------+---------+---------+
|ID    |  Name1  |  Name2  |
+------+---------+---------+
|   1  |     A   |     B   |
|   2  |     C   |     D   |
|   3  |     E   |     F   |
+------+---------+---------+
```

`df2`:

```
+------+-------+
|ID    |  key  |
+------+-------+
|   1  |   w   |
|   1  |   x   |
|   2  |   y   |
|   3  |   z   |
+------+-------+
```

Now, I want to create a new column in `df1` that contains all key values denoted in `df2`. So, I aim for the result:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+
|ID    |  Name1  |  Name2  |  keys   |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1  |     A   |     B   |   w,x   |
|   2  |     C   |     D   |    y    |
|   3  |     E   |     F   |    z    |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Ultimately, I want to find a solution for an arbitrary amount of keys.

My attempt in PySpark:

```
def get_keys(id):
    x = df2.where(df2.ID == id).select('key')

    return x

df_keys = df1.withColumn("keys", get_keys(col('ID')))
```

In the above code, `x` is a dataframe. Since the second argument of the `.withColumn` function needs to be an Column type variable, I am not sure how to mutate `x` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `collect_list` function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.ID == df2.ID).drop(df2.ID)

df3.groupBy('ID','Name1','Name2').agg(collect_list('key').alias('keys')).show()

#+---+-----+-----+------+
#| ID|Name1|Name2|  keys|
#+---+-----+-----+------+
#|  1|    A|    B|[w, x]|
#|  3|    C|    F|   [z]|
#|  2|    B|    D|   [y]|
#+---+-----+-----+------+
```

If you want only unique keys you can use `collect_set`